# Remove asp.net event on code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I want to remove an event in code behind.

For example my control is like this.

```
<asp:Textbox ID="txtName" runat="server" OnTextChanged="txtName_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

I want to remove the `OnTextChanged` programmatically.. how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C#, you can add and remove event handlers quite easily from the code-behind:

```
// Add event handler:
txtName.OnTextChanged += new EventHandler(txtName_Changed);

// Remove event handler:
txtName.OnTextChanged -= new EventHandler(txtName_Changed);
```

Comment: It does seem a bit weird that you have to instantiate a new EventHandler first, before you can remove it from the event list of that control.

Comment: Is there any way to do this on a method I do not have access to? My problem I have a 3rd party assembly that adds an Event its handler is protected and I need to override that behavior with my own event handler.

Answer (score 3):

In VB.NET code:

```
RemoveHandler txtName.OnTextChanged, addressof txtName_Changed
```

Or in C#:

http://www.devnewsgroups.net/dotnetframework/t16784-remove-event-handlers-net.aspx

```
obj.Click += new EventHandler(BeAlert); // register an event handler
obj.Click -= new EventHandler(BeAlert); // unregister the same event handler
```

Comment: Here's an example in C#: http://www.devnewsgroups.net/dotnetframework/t16784-remove-event-handlers-net.aspx