# Removing event handler from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, event-handling

I have an asp.net dropdownlist like this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddLevel" runat="server" Width="95%" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddYear_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

on some condition i am trying to remove the OnSelectedIndexChanged event handler.I tried

```
ddLevel.SelectedIndexChanged -=ddYear_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

It did not work. Then, I tried

```
ddLevel.SelectedIndexChanged -=new EventHandler(ddYear_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

But both of them are not working. When I check the source of the page, I can still see onchange event.

I checked these two links [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516744/asp-net-c-sharp-prevent-firing-selectedindexchanged-event-while-changing-index-f) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151842/remove-asp-net-event-on-code-behind). I do not understand what I am doing wrong. I'd like to knwo if there is another way to do this. Is the cause of this that I am doing this in the `Page_Load` event?

Comment: What's the reason why do you have to remove the event handler?

Comment: In case you don't get the eventhandler removed, you can add a condition in the event handler itself which checks if the code should be executed

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below should unsubscribe from the event, make sure the execution doesn't come to the event subscription again after that point on `page_load` event.

```
ddLevel.SelectedIndexChanged -=ddYear_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply.i was seeing **onchange** in page source because my dropdown autopostback was set to true.the line ddLevel.SelectedIndexChanged -=ddYear_SelectedIndexChanged does remove the event handler from dropdown.but when the page reloads the event handler again get added and fires the SelectedIndexChanged event.any way to avoid this unwanted behaviour?

Comment: @shreesha: so, what I guessed is the issue. Stop adding it again.

Comment: @ChrithJ but the event handler is in my .aspx page.so each time page reloads it will be get added again.do i need to dynamically add event handler in back end c# code or is there any other way?

Comment: @shreesha: Add it only if IsPostback false in the page load.